# Convert cURL form file post with token authentication to C#

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, httpclient, webclient

I'm trying to convert below cURL into a HttpClient or similar using C#.

```
curl --form "file=@C:\files\test.csv" https://company.com/api/v0/imports/api_name?token=123456asdfgh2345asdfg12345sdfgh2345sdfg123asd
```

I've been trying below but it's throwing me a 401.

> StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

Here's the code:

```
private async Task<string> PostAttachment(byte[] data, Uri url, string contentType, string token)
{
    HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {   
        form.Add(content);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, form);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); }}}
```

And called here

```
var uri = new Uri(@"https://company.com/api/v0/imports/api_name");
PostAttachment(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv), uri, "text/csv", token);`
```

I've been trying many other similar posts here but nothing got the authentication with tokens.

Comment: you have the token as part of the URL in cURL. If that works, why not do the same for c#?

Comment: I have. throws me a StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

Comment: so to confirm. the cURL works?

Comment: @Nkosi I don't have outbound to test it personally but it is working in the old console application.